# handle null in Comparator class

Tags: java, null, cyclomatic-complexity

> I have a class `LoanAccount` that contains an attributes `creationDate` and  `loanAmount`.
>
> I want to implement a Comparator that sorts the accounts by loan amount in descending order.
>   When the loan amounts are the same, sorts the accounts
>   ascending by date.

The code look like this:

**Class**

```
public class LoanAccount {
    private String id;
    private Date creationDate;
    private BigDecimal loanAmount;
}
```

**Comparator**

```
public class LoanAccountAmountComparator implements Comparator<LoanAccount> {

    @Override
    public int compare(LoanAccount o1, LoanAccount o2) {
        if (o1 == null) {
            if (o2 == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        if (o2 == null) {
            return 1;
        }
        if (o1.getLoanAmount() == null) {
            if (o2.getLoanAmount() == null) {
                return 0;
            }
            return -1;
        }
        if (o2.getLoanAmount() == null) {
            return 1;
        }

        int comparedLoanAmount = o2.getLoanAmount().compareTo(o1.getLoanAmount());
        if (comparedLoanAmount == 0) {
            if (o1.getCreationDate() == null) {
                if (o2.getCreationDate() == null) {
                    return 0;
                }
                return -1;
            }
            if (o2.getCreationDate() == null) {
                return 1;
            }
            return o1.getCreationDate().compareTo(o2.getCreationDate());
        } else {
            return comparedLoanAmount;
        }
    }
}
```

Objects `o1`, `o2` can be null. Fields `creationDate` and `loanAmount` can be null.

I want to ask you if there are better ways to handle null pointer exception in compareTo method.

For me it looks like there are too many if conditions

Comment: @dfhwze I've posted the real class.

Comment: some useful comparison strategies in Java: https://www.baeldung.com/java-8-comparator-comparing and https://stackoverflow.com/a/20093589/11523568

Answer (score 14, accepted):

it is possible to handle null pointer exception using [Comparator.comparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparing-java.util.function.Function-) static method. If you want to comparing `loanAmount` fields in your objects and you want that every not null value is greater than `null` you can use [Comparator.nullFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#nullsFirst-java.util.Comparator-) method in combination with `Comparator.comparing` like the below code:

```
Comparator.comparing(LoanAccount::getLoanAmount,
                     Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
```

`NaturalOrder` is a method returning a comparator that compares Comparable objects in natural order.
You can also combine more comparators in a chain with method [Comparator.thenComparing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#thenComparing-java.util.Comparator-) like the code below:

```java
Comparator
        .comparing(LoanAccount::getLoanAmount,
                   Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        .thenComparing(LoanAccount::getCreationDate, 
                       Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder()))
        .compare(o1, o2);
```

Now you can rewrite your comparator with equal behaviour shortly:

```java
public class LoanAccountAmountComparator
        implements Comparator<LoanAccount> {

    @Override
    public int compare(LoanAccount o1, LoanAccount o2) {
        if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
        if (o1 == null) return -1;
        if (o2 == null) return 1;
        return Comparator
                .comparing(LoanAccount::getLoanAmount,
                           nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))
                .thenComparing(LoanAccount::getCreationDate,
                               nullsFirst(naturalOrder()))
                .compare(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

Note: the use of class `Date` is discouraged, it is better if you use instead the `java.time` package classes for time related code.

Comment: Two more things... First you could pass the inner comparator itself to `Comparator.nullsFirst()`, which would make that comparator handle `null` automatically (thus avoiding the three if at the beginning). Second, that whole thing become your comparator, so you don't need the LoanAccountAmountComparator class at all. Simply move the comparator construction to some other place (for example, the LoadAccount class), and store it into a public static field (lets say `ACCOUNT_BY_AMOUNT_AND_DATE_COMPARATOR`)...

Comment: @jwatkins You are right.

Answer (score 7):

Here is another twist, roughly similar to dariosicily's proposal.

It differs in the following points:

- It create the aggregated comparator only once, then store it in a static field. Why? Because functions such as `Comparator.nullsFirst()` and `Comparator.comparing()` implies object allocation, which you definitely want to avoid if your comparator is called from tight loops (for example, a sort or tree insertion algorithm).
- Null checks on the LoadAccount objects themselves have also been delegated to `Comparator.nullsFirst()`. That means that absolutely no `if` statement is required!
- I moved that comparator to a public, static field of a utility class. I have learned from personal experience that comparators on domain model objects very often come in "families". In different places, you want different sorting strategies, for the same objects. Here, for demonstration, I also included one comparator for `loadAmount` (that is, without fallback on tie), and another one for `creationDate`. But you can see how this idea can be generalized.
- In this sample, I have adopted an uncommon indentation strategy. I think this is justified in this case because it helps make it easier to see which fields are sorted by each comparator, and in which order. This is of great importance when you have comparators that involve a significant number of fields.

```
    public class LoanAccountAmountComparators {

        /**
         * A comparator that sort LoanAccounts, by load's amount, in decreasing order.
         */
        public static final Comparator<LoanAccount> BY_AMOUNT = 
            Comparator.nullsFirst(
                Comparator.comparing(
                    LoanAccount::getLoanAmount, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                );
            );

        /**
         * A comparator that sort LoanAccounts, by creation date, in ascending order.
         */
        public static final Comparator<LoanAccount> BY_DATE = 
            Comparator.nullsFirst(
                Comparator.comparing(
                    LoanAccount::getCreationDate, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                );
            );

        /**
         * A comparator that sort LoanAccounts, by creation amount (in descending order),
         * then by date (in ascending order).
         */
        public static final Comparator<LoanAccount> BY_AMOUNT_AND_DATE = 
            Comparator.nullsFirst(
                Comparator.comparing(
                    LoanAccount::getLoanAmount, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.reverseOrder())
                ).thenComparing(
                    LoanAccount::getCreationDate, Comparator.nullsFirst(Comparator.naturalOrder())
                );
            );
    }
```

It should be noted that, in this example, all fields involved are indeed some kind of objects. If, however, your comparator would involve fields containing primitive types, then you should use the corresponding `Comparator.comparing<primitiveType>` function (that is, never let some primitive be boxed to object only so it can be compared to `Comparator.naturalOrder()`.